# How cancel navigation in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

In my code of RichTextBox in my Windows Phone application I have:

```
 var link = new Hyperlink();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkUrl))
                        {
                            link.NavigateUri = new Uri(linkUrl);
                        }
                        link.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
                        link.TargetName = "_blank";

                        var linkText = new Run() { Text = linkDesc };
                        link.Inlines.Add(linkText);
                        link.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(NavidateTo);

                        paragraph.Inlines.Add(link);

 private static void NavidateTo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {

            if (MessageBox.Show(
                             Constants.BrowserNavigating,
                             "",
                              MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
            {
              //cancel Navigation
            }
            else
            {
                StateManager.Set("Browser", "true");
            }
        }
```

How can I cancel navigation in NavidateTo method?

**Update**

private static void NavidateTo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {

```
    if (MessageBox.Show(
                     Constants.BrowserNavigating,
                     "",
                      MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
    {
        //cancel Navigation
        var phoneApplicationFrame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
        if (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame != null)
            phoneApplicationFrame.Navigating += new NavigatingCancelEventHandler(NavigationService_Navigating);
    }
    else
    {
        StateManager.Set("Browser", "true");
    }
}

public static void NavigationService_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

This doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Use this.NavigationService.StopLoading();

Also consider this method:

Subscribe to the `Navigating` event.

```
void NavigationService_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Don't allow refreshing of a static page
    if (DO SOME CHECKS)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
}
```

And take a look at this article over at msdn.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigating.aspx

Comment: it navagete in any case, see my Update

Comment: @revolutionkpi I'm not talking about the Hyperlink , I'm talking about NavigationService

Comment: ok, I will try, but how can I do this, can you update your unswer with this, please?

Comment: @revolutionkpi subscribe to phoneApplicationFrame.Navigating before NavigateTo, in the constructor or something.

Comment: I do as You write, just try to do the sample example, it doesn't work it navigates)