# Cancel opening link in browser

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my Windows phone application I use RichTextBox element

I have a hyperlink on it, and when user click on it there is a dialog: Do you want to open this link in exteranl browser. If user say no, external browser shouldn't be opened. I cancel navigation but in any case  - external browser opens. How can I cancel opening link in browser?

```
//Constructor
        static Helper()
                {
                    var phoneApplicationFrame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
                    if (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame != null)
                    {
                        phoneApplicationFrame.Navigating += new NavigatingCancelEventHandler(NavigationService_Navigating);
                    }

                }

link.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
                            link.MouseOverForeground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
                            link.TargetName = "_blank";

                            var linkText = new Run() { Text = linkDesc };
                            link.Inlines.Add(linkText);
                            link.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(NavidateTo);

private static void NavidateTo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {

            if (MessageBox.Show(
                             Constants.BrowserNavigating,
                             "",
                              MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
            {
                StateManager.Set("ExternalBrowser", "true");
            }
            else
            {
                StateManager.Set("Browser", "true");
            }
        }

        public static void NavigationService_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            var res = StateManager.Get("ExternalBrowser");
            if (res != null)
            {
                StateManager.Remove("ExternalBrowser");
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: we cant tell you whats wrong with your code if you dont show us your code..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How cancel navigation in RichTextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547834/how-cancel-navigation-in-richtextbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than have the HyperlinkButton open the link itself, don't specify the NavigationUri but handle the `Tap` event yourself.

In the eventhandler ask the question and only open the browser if they say yes.
This will be much simpler than trying to cancel something that is already in progress.